# Loading multiple image layers on top of background image on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to create an HTML color visualizer for steel buildings. This will be placed on my company's website. I'm wanting to see if it is possible (in HTML) to load image layers (in their fixed positions) onto a canvas background, after a visitor clicks on a color swatch.

[Here](https://dakotasteelandtrim.com/visualizer/) is a similar solution I am seeking.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-red";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">Tan Wall</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">Red Roof</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(4)">Black Garage</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(5)">Black Trim</button>
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Canvas-Background.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Wall-Tan.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Roof-Red.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Garage-Black.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Trim-Black.png" style="width:100%">

</div>
```

For example, when a visitor clicks on the "Red Roof" swatch I want the "Red-Roof.png" layer to load on top of the white building canvas. The positioning would be perfect since it is positioned correctly in the image file already. From there, I'd like the customer to add more image layers such as "Tan Wall" until the building combination fits their preferences. The final image should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0RRp.jpg) after clicking all of the buttons.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by css `absolute positioning`.
Additionally I recommend to use `.classList.toggle` instead of replacing the `.className`:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].classList.toggle("active");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.toggle("w3-red")
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
}
.mySlides.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(1)">Tan Wall</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(2)">Red Roof</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(3)">Black Garage</button>
<button class="w3-button demo" onclick="currentDiv(4)">Black Trim</button>
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position: relative;">
  <img src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Canvas-Background.png" style="width:100%;position: absolute ;z-index:-1">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Wall-Tan.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Roof-Red.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Garage-Black.png" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Trim-Black.png" style="width:100%">

</div>
```

**EDIT:**
*According to the asker's comment...*

- **Use `absolute` position** on every image, and...
- **Use toggle buttons** (checkbox behavior) instead of hiding all images on button click and showing only one (radio button behavior)

Comment: Thank you that is great! But how would you go about leaving the red roof in place when I click the other buttons? Like have a red roof and tan walls and black garage?

Comment: @ChazzDecker I edited my question according to your comment. And if this  satisfies your request, you can mark my answer accepted by the checkmark.   Happy coding!

Comment: Genius! Thank you! Now I need to add about 15 more colors for each element (trim, roof, wall, and garage) and I can't wait to expand on your code. I'll update you on my progress. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay here is what I have so far: http://metaldepotinc.com/BD.html It works great but there's one problem. I can change colors when clicking the buttons from left to right, but if I click from right to left, the last layer in the sequence stays above all the other layers. So what I need to do is clear the previous layer when clicking on the next layer. Do you have any idea how to do this?